# laravel 5.6: How to display each product and the available brand s in a table given that each product has multiple brands

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'am a newbie in laravel and I'am trying to develop an application, which has a section with a table that lists each product, the available brands,the available quantities,the selling prices.Each product has multiple brands

> I have three tables involved:
>
> 1ST TABLE Items_master: this table stores the product names, buying and selling price
>
> 2ND TABLE Stock_quantities: this table stores the product quantities according to the shop by product_id and shop_id.
>
> 3RD TABLE item_brands: this table stores the brands of each product based on product_id and shop_id.

Here is the code

MAIN QUERY TO GET PRODUCT NAME, CATEGORIES AND ITEM QUANTITY

```
 $details=items_master::select('items_masters.id as 
   product_id','items_masters.name as item_name','items_masters.category','buying_price','selling_price','item_quantities.product_id','item_quantities.quantity','categories.id','categories.serial')       
 ->join('item_quantities','items_masters.id','=','item_quantities.item_id')
  ->join('categories','categories.id','=','items_masters.category')
   ->where([['item_quantities.shop_id', '=',$shop]] )
  ->groupBY('product_id')
   ->get();
```

QUERY TO GET THE PRODUCT IDs

```
    $product_ids = collect($details)->pluck('product_id');
```

QUERY TO GET THE PRODUCT BRANDS

```
   $brands = item_brands::whereIn('pid', $product_ids)
   ->where('shop_id', $shop)
   ->where('status', 0)
   ->get();
```

CODE IN THE VIEW

```
   <div class="table-responsive">      
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
             <thead>
              <tr>
            
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Brands</th>
           <th>Stock Qty</th>
           <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            
            
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($details as $detail)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$detail->item_name}} </td>
            <td><div class="form-group">
          
                   
        @foreach($brands as $brand )

             <span>{{$brand->name}}</span>
         @endforeach

          
          </div>
         </td>
            <td>{{$detail->quantity.' '.$detail->units}} </td>
            <td >

            <td>{{$detail->category}} </td>
            <td >
            <b>Ksh. {{$detail->selling_price}}</b>
            
                          </td>
               </tr>
                       @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Given the above code , I get all the brands for all products in the table listed against  each product. I need  each product to only display its brands on its row e.g

Product: Tablet  |   Brands: samsung, apple

Product: Desktop |    Brands: HP,Lenovo

CURRRENLY THIS IS WHAT APPEARS

Product: Tablet  |    Brands: samsung, apple,HP,Lenovo

Product: Desktop |    Brands: samsung, apple,HP,Lenovo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a collection method to constrain what brands are used in the foreach? IE:

```
@foreach($brands->where('pid', $detail->product_id) as $brand )
    <span>{{$brand->name}}</span>
@endforeach
```

Since you get all brands for every product, this will let you just pick the brands for your current `$detail`.

Edit: but to be honest, I feel like all 3 queries could be written into 1 eloquent query, but I would have to see all 3 models with relationships.